# I can't make return do the same as print (Python)

Tags: python

```
sopa=(["PATO", "BOI", "GATO", "CAO"], ["XPATOW", "GATOPA", "YWBIVZ","ZWCAOB", "ABBOIL"])

def obtem_palavras(sopa):
    return sopa[0]

def obtem_grelha(sopa):
    return sopa[1]


def encontra_palavras(sopa):
    tuplo_palavra = obtem_palavras(sopa)
    tuplo_linha = obtem_grelha(sopa)
    for item in tuplo_palavra:
        for item1 in tuplo_linha:
            if item in item1:
                return item, tuplo_linha.index(item1), item1.index(item)
```

The outcome i want is `(("PATO",0,1),("BOI",4,2),("GATO",1,0),("CAO",3,2))`
By using return I only get the 1st part right `"('PATO', 0, 1)"`
And by using print i get each info in different lines

```
PATO 0 1 
BOI 4 2
GATO 1 0
CAO 3 2
```

`encontra_palavras(sopa)` must give me the same word in  `tuplo_palavra` and `tuplo_linha`, the position it has in `tuplo_linha`, and the position in begins inside item
I'm new to Python, i don't know if anyone can help. I have to use RETURN and no PRINT :) Thanks

Comment: _"I can't make return do the same as print"_ - that's because they aren't designed to do the same thing.

Comment: `return` immediately terminates the execution of the whole function.

Comment: `return` passes the control back to caller. If you use it inside `for`, you will end up returning only what you get in the first iteration.

Comment: You can only `return` once. Perhaps you meant to `yield`.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to this without using print?

Comment: @KellyBaptista do you want it to print to the console?

Comment: yes...even if I use 'print', the information i want to outcome is separated in different lines (like if I clicked enter in a settence), it doesn't create a list. I don't know how to solve it...Sorry guys, I'm new to this

Answer (score 0):

```
sopa=(["PATO", "BOI", "GATO", "CAO"], ["XPATOW", "GATOPA", "YWBIVZ","ZWCAOB", "ABBOIL"])

def obtem_palavras(sopa):
    return sopa[0]

def obtem_grelha(sopa):
    return sopa[1]


def encontra_palavras(sopa):
    tuplo_palavra = obtem_palavras(sopa)
    tuplo_linha = obtem_grelha(sopa)

    final_lst=[]
    for item in tuplo_palavra:
        for item1 in tuplo_linha:
            if item in item1:
                lst=[]
                lst.append(item)
                lst.append(tuplo_linha.index(item1))
                lst.append(item1.index(item))
                final_lst.append(tuple(lst))
    return tuple(final_lst)            
encontra_palavras(sopa)
```

Try using this one! Created a list, appended all the tuples in it, and returned it when the function finished executing.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

You want the function `encontra_palavras` to do some work for each item in `tuplo_palavra`, to *accrue* (collect) the results of the work into a collection, and then return that collection as it's return value.

What you're actually doing is asking `encontra_palavras` to perform some work for each item in `tuplo_palavra`, doing the work for the very first item, and then returning that single result, without ever visiting the other items in `tuplo_palavra`.

To get the result you want, you must change the code so that instead of *returning* from the inner-most loop you *add the result to a collection* and then only after all loops have completed will you return the entire collection.

It will look like this:

```
def encontra_palavras(sopa):
    tuplo_palavra = obtem_palavras(sopa)
    tuplo_linha = obtem_grelha(sopa)
    results = [] # make an empty list collection to hold results.
    for item in tuplo_palavra:
        for item1 in tuplo_linha:
            if item in item1:
                # add to the results collection a tuple with the result for this loop
                results.append( (item, tuplo_linha.index(item1), item1.index(item)) )

     return results # return the entire collection now that all work is done.
```

Comment: Thank you Larry for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two main approaches that you can use: you can build a tuple in your `for` loop, and then return it, or you can make your function a generator, then use that generator to build a tuple.

Approach #1: concatenating to an empty tuple

```
def encontra_palavras(sopa):
    result = ()
    tuplo_palavra = obtem_palavras(sopa)
    tuplo_linha = obtem_grelha(sopa)
    for item in tuplo_palavra:
        for item1 in tuplo_linha:
            if item in item1:
                result +=  ((item, tuplo_linha.index(item1), item1.index(item)),)
    return result
```

This is the simplest way, but isn't efficent because a new tuple is created for every `+=` operation. You could also build a list that you turn into a tuple before returning.

Approach #2: tuple comprehension (technically a generator expression that gets passed to `tuple`)

```
def encontra_palavras(sopa):
    tuplo_palavra = obtem_palavras(sopa)
    tuplo_linha = obtem_grelha(sopa)
    return tuple((item, tuplo_linha.index(item1), item1.index(item)) 
                     for item in tuplo_palavra 
                     for item1 in tuplo_linha 
                     if item in item1)
```

Approach #3 Generator

```
def encontra_palavras(sopa):
    result = ()
    tuplo_palavra = obtem_palavras(sopa)
    tuplo_linha = obtem_grelha(sopa)
    for item in tuplo_palavra:
        for item1 in tuplo_linha:
            if item in item1:
                yield item, tuplo_linha.index(item1), item1.index(item)

def encontra_palavras_as_tuple(sopa):
    return tuple(encontra_palavras(sopa))
```

If you usually just iterate over the result of `encontra_palavras`, this approach is better because you can use the generator directly without turning it into a tuple.  This means you can iterate through the items of `encontra_palavras` without storing them in memory (this is called lazy evaluation).